# Icecast radio status does not work

Tags: php, icecast

So I'm busy on this website, and it needs a radio on it. They're using a icecast server, so I grabbed a Icecast status from the internet:

```
    <?php
$icecast_url='http://178.32.13.195:8002';

$output = file_get_contents($icecast_url);

$search='#<div class="newscontent">.*?Point /(.*?)<.*?href="(.*?)">M3U<.*?Listeners.*?class="streamdata">(.*?)<.*?Song:.*?class="streamdata">(.*?)<.*?</div>#si';
preg_match_all($search, $output, $matches);

$j=count($matches[0]);
for ($i=0;$i<$j; $i++) {

    $point_name=$matches[1][$i];
    $pount_m3u=$icecast_url.$matches[2][$i];
    $point_listners_count=$matches[3][$i];
    $point_current_song=$matches[4][$i];
//
    echo 'mount point: <b>'.$point_name.'</b>
';
    echo 'm3u: <a href="'.$pount_m3u.'">'.$pount_m3u.'</a>
';
    echo 'listners_count: <b>'.$point_listners_count.'</b>
';
    echo 'point_current_song: <b>'. $point_current_song.'</b>


';
}
?>
```

But it doesn't work. It just shows a blank page. Does any one of you know what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: No, are you getting any errors? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php tag error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Word of advice from one whos burned his finger many a time - "Do not screenscrape, thou shalt suffer more than thou canst imagine.."

Comment: @JayBlanchard Nope, still a blank page.

Answer (score 2):

They are using Icecast 2.4.0, which got a redesigned Admin interface, and this breaks your parsing code.
Please just don't try to parse the html, it will break whenever they update Icecast and the HTML changes.
Instead you could try the newly introduced status-json.xsl, i.e. for this server it is located here: `http://178.32.13.195:8002/status-json.xsl`

Please note, unfortunately due to a bug in the json xslt this is not valid JSON. This issue  is fixed in Icecast 2.4.1, so if you have access to the server you can update to Icecast 2.4.1 soon (will be available probably in a few weeks). If you don't have access to the server, there isn't much you can do, but parsing HTML is the worst possible method.

Comment: 2.4.1 was released, distribution packages are becoming available.